# mysql index optimization for a table with multiple indexes that index some of the same columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table that stores some basic data about visitor sessions on third party web sites. This is its structure:

```
id, site_id, unixtime, unixtime_last, ip_address, uid
```

There are four indexes: `id`, `site_id/unixtime`, `site_id/ip_address`, and `site_id/uid`

There are many different types of ways that we query this table, and all of them are specific to the site_id. The index with unixtime is used to display the list of visitors for a given date or time range. The other two are used to find all visits from an IP address or a "uid" (a unique cookie value created for each visitor), as well as determining if this is a new visitor or a returning visitor.

Obviously storing site_id inside 3 indexes is inefficient for both write speed and storage, but I see no way around it, since I need to be able to quickly query this data for a given specific site_id.

Any ideas on making this more efficient?

I don't really understand B-trees besides some very basic stuff, but it's more efficient to have the left-most column of an index be the one with the least variance - correct? Because I considered having the site_id being the second column of the index for both ip_address and uid but I think that would make the index less efficient since the IP and UID are going to vary more than the site ID will, because we only have about 8000 unique sites per database server, but millions of unique visitors across all ~8000 sites on a daily basis.

I've also considered removing site_id from the IP and UID indexes completely, since the chances of the same visitor going to multiple sites that share the same database server are quite small, but in cases where this does happen, I fear it could be quite slow to determine if this is a new visitor to this site_id or not. The query would be something like:

```
select id from sessions where uid = 'value' and site_id = 123 limit 1
```

... so if this visitor had visited this site before, it would only need to find one row with this site_id before it stopped. This wouldn't be super fast necessarily, but acceptably fast. But say we have a site that gets 500,000 visitors a day, and a particular visitor loves this site and goes there 10 times a day. Now they happen to hit another site on the same database server for the first time. The above query could take quite a long time to search through all of the potentially thousands of rows for this UID, scattered all over the disk, since it wouldn't be finding one for this site ID.

Any insight on making this as efficient as possible would be appreciated :)

Update - this is a MyISAM table with MySQL 5.0. My concerns are both with performance as well as storage space. This table is both read and write heavy. If I had to choose between performance and storage, my biggest concern is performance - but both are important.

We use memcached heavily in all areas of our service, but that's not an excuse to not care about the database design. I want the database to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: storage engine? mysql version? And how do you want to make this more efficient - disk-usage-wise or performance wise? And do you have actual problems to solve or is this just a rhetoric question?

Comment: mysql 5.0, myisam engine. I'm concerned both about storage space as well as performance, since this is both a read and write heavy table. Yes, actual problem. :)

Comment: Have you read High Performance MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

> I don't really understand B-trees besides some very basic stuff, but it's more efficient to have the left-most column of an index be the one with the least variance - correct?

There is one important property of B-tree indices you need to be aware of: It is possible (efficient) to search for an arbitrary *prefix* of the full key, but not a *suffix*. If you have an index `site_ip(site_id, ip)`, and you ask for `where ip = 1.2.3.4`, MySQL will not use the site_ip index. If you instead had `ip_site(ip, site_id)`, then MySQL would be able to use the ip_site index.

The is a second property of B-tree indices you should be aware of as well: they are sorted. A b-tree index can be used for queries like `where site_id < 40`.

There is also an important property of disk drives to keep in mind: sequential reads are cheap, seeks are not. If there are any columns used that are not in the index, MySQL must read the row from the table data. That's generally a seek, and slow. So if MySQL believes it'd wind up reading even a small percent of the table like this, it'll instead ignore the index. One big table scan (a sequential read) is usually faster than random reads of even a few percent of the rows in a table.

The same, by the way, applies to seeks through an index. Finding a key in a B-tree actually potentially requires a few seeks, so you'll find that `WHERE site_id > 800 AND ip = '1.2.3.4'` may not use the `site_ip` index, becuase each site_id requires several index seeks to find the start of the 1.2.3.4 records for that site. The `ip_site` index, however, would be used.

Ultimately, you're going to have to make liberal use of benchmarking and `EXPLAIN` to figure out the best indices for your database. Remember, you can freely add and drop indices as needed. Non-unique indices are not part of your data model; they are merely an optimization.

PS: Benchmark InnoDB as well, it often has better concurrent performance. Same with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using ip as a string than change it to INT UNSIGNED column and use INET_ATON(expr) and INET_NTOA(expr) function to deal with this. Indexing on integer value is more efficient than indexing on strings of variable length.

Comment: Make sure to be IPv6-incompatible. Year 2000, here we come!

Answer (score 0):

Well indexes trade storage for performance. Its hard if you want both. Its hard to optimize this any further without know all the queries you run and their quantities per interval.

What you have will work. If you're running into a bottleneck, you'll need to find out whether its cpu,ram,disk and/or network and adjust accordingly. Its hard and wrong to prematurely optimize.

You probably want to switch to innodb if you have any updates, other wise myisam is good for insert/select. Also since your row size is small, you could look into mysql cluster (nbd). There is also an archive engine that can help with storage requirements but partitioning in 5.1 is probably a better thing to look into.

Flipping the order of your index doesn't make any sense, if these indexes are already used in all of your queries.

> but it's more efficient to have the left-most column of an index be the one with the least variance - correct?

not sure but I haven't heard this before. Doesn't seem true to me for this application. The index order matters for sorting and by having multiple unique 1st most index fields, allows more possible queries to use index.